# Почему не работает разговорный динамик на iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, динамик

Нужна помощь!!!
На iPhone XS не работает разговорный динамик при звонке, а когда смотрю видео, слушаю музыку и так далее он работает, пробовал обновлять до iOS 16.6, точно не знаю сбрасывался ли до заводских настроек так как телефон был куплен б/у. Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой помогите

Answer (score 0):

Наверно я тут напишу 3 пункта, возможно они вам помогут:

> 1. Проверьте, нет ли каких-либо физических преград на динамике разговора, таких как пыль, грязь или посторонние предметы. Проверьте
>    отверстие динамика и, если необходимо, очистите его мягкой щеткой или
>    сжатым воздухом.
> 2. Убедитесь, что настройки уровня звука во время звонка находятся на максимальном уровне. Во время звонка нажмите на кнопки громкости на
>    боковой или верхней стороне устройства, чтобы увеличить громкость.
> 3. Попробуйте перезагрузить устройство. Нажмите и удерживайте кнопку включения/выключения до появления ползунка "Выключить". Переместите
>    ползунок, чтобы выключить iPhone, и затем снова включите его, нажав и
>    удерживая кнопку включения/выключения.

Надеюсь я вам помог, прошу вас дать фидбек в комментарий.

Comment: Серьезно?) Обычно, люди что не могут проверить предоставленные вами пункты - даже этот сайт найти не могут) даже самому стало интересно почитать что автор ответит) вангую - он не ответит ничего

Comment: В нашей жизни бывает всё, но вы правы.

Comment: Все выше перечисленное я сделал еще давно, сетки динамика чисты, динамик сам по себе работает но когда я звоню он не работает, приходится по громкой связи разговаривать, можно ли проверить как-нибудь например на пк или на телефоне уже самому, просто в сервис не хочется идти и отдавать деньги за то что я смогу сам сделать.